# Eclipse CDT - Tool Chain Editor - Current Builder : GNU Make vs GNU Make Builder

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, fortran, gnu-make

I'm trying to better understand and ensure I properly configure my build settings in Eclipse for both C/C++ and Fortran.  I notice that in the Tool Chain Editor settings I am able to select from several different types of builders.  Two of which are GNU Make and GNU Make Builder.  I've created dummy hello world projects for both, built them, and then ran a directory comparison using Meld.  I can't seem to see any significant difference between the two builder types.  Can anyone shed some light on what the differences between these are and which one is best to use?

Comment: I guess, it is the same thing.

Comment: That's what I guess to.  Just seeing if I'm missing something.